# relative path of excel for c#

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I just had such this problem here. I am trying to use a relative path to link to an excel file within the same directory of the exe file itself.
When I use

```
Excel.Workbook wkbook = exapp.Workbooks.Open(@".\test.xlsx");
```

I put my exe file in the f drive. It turned out that the exe file altered the test.xlsx file in the C:\Users\\Documents folder(And also it somehow created the test.xlsx itself).
However when I use ".\xx.txt" or "xx.txt" , it worked perfectly well.

Can anyone tell me what to do?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To get a filepath relative to the currently executing exe, you can use the following:

```
string exeDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Excel.Workbook wkbook = exapp.Workbooks.Open(System.IO.Path.Combine(exeDir, "test.xlsx"));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class instance of `Excel.Application`, the default path for files can be stored in its `DefaultFilePath` property; for example, these two lines set the default file path for the xlApp object to the current assembly's default directory.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.DefaultFilePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

You can set every directory of your choice, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be: don't use relative paths. Here is some code to explicitly set the path:

```
var executableFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
Excel.Workbook wkbook = exapp.Workbooks.Open(executableFolderPath + @"\test.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But may I ask why there is the difference between excel and text file?